# Display data in Angular Elements

Tags: javascript, angular, frontend, angular-elements

I'm using Angular elements to show a angular page inside an existing Spring-Boot project.

I have an inquire button with which I load data from backend in the component typescript file and then display it on the screen. I'm using two different methods for it :

1. {{data.name}}
2. Making a form and then doing form.patchValue()

Both are working fine when I run the angular project in local server but when run the page via the Spring boot project (Angular elements), **I'm unable to display data via the first method i.e {{data.name}}.**

Any idea why?

Code:-

component.**ts**

```
data = {}
populateData(data) {
 this.data = data
}
```

component.**html**

```
<input value="{{data.name}}" />
```

---

Comment: Well, it looks like you are trying to show the property `name` of an array. Which does not exist. Could you check what does  `data` contain when you run you app from springboot ? Maybe using a `console.log`.

Comment: Is the API call to your backend returning data successfully when you're running with Spring Boot?

Comment: Hey. 

And Backend data is coming successfully and I've checked by using console.log.

Comment: @Nicolas that was a type I've edited it. :D

Answer (score 0):

> When you're the **Angular project** with **Spring boot,** it's
>   rendered as a HTML page not compiled and run as a server with the
>   angular-CLI, that' why it's not working!

Comment: So how can I call call the service and display data?